# JQuery custombox CSS scrolling issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm using JQuery custombox and for some reason having trouble enabling scrolling/scrollbar on the mobile view of the page.

The JqueryCustomBoxCSS shown below  enables the custombox to be shown middle of the page on a PC but changing that JqueryCustomBox CSS to enable scrolling on the mobile view by changing it to height: 100% and overflow:auto...then effects the main view on pc where the custombox will be at the top of the screen rather than middle.

Can anybody help? I'll post my css/html below and a screenshot or 2 (edit just noticed my rep is not high enough to post images sorry).

So what css can I use to get the mobile view to work with scroll and not effect the full screen position of the custombox?

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!!

```css
.custombox-show {
  visibility: visible;
}
.custombox-modal {
  height: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.custombox-error {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
```

```html
<div class="four columns">
  <div class="milestones-wrap">
    <div class="milestones-wrap-icon">
      <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/images/about/1950s.jpg ")" alt="" />
    </div>
    <p>Movies, movies, marriage!</p>
    <a href="#modal3" class="list-group-item" id="slide">
      <p>read more...</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="modal3" style="display: none;" class="modal-example-content">
  <button type="button" class="close" onclick="$.fn.custombox('close');">&times;</button>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="sixteen columns">
      <div class="milestones-wrap">
        <div class="milestones-wrap-icon">
          <img src="@Url.Content(" ~/images/about/1950s.jpg ")" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sixteen columns">
      <div class="modal-example-body">
        <p class="format-text"><span class="format-span">1955: </span> Mario submitted artwork to Howard Hughes for the movie 'Son Of Sinbad'.</p>
        <p class="format-text"><span class="format-span">1955: </span> Mario submitted artwork to Howard Hughes for the movie 'Underwater!'.</p>
        <p class="format-text"><span class="format-span">1951: </span> Mario submitted artwork to Howard Hughes for the movie 'His Kind Of Woman'.</p>
        <p class="format-text"><span class="format-span">1950: </span> Mario submitted artwork to Howard Hughes for the movie 'Vendetta'.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net or at least include your jquery?

Comment: Have you tried using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: The css above is from the jquerycustombox.css file. I've not used jsfiddle.net before. What's it for?